# "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" occurs while adding images using ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, imageicon

Firstly i applied panel on whole background & then created a label to set an image here.
[JFrame picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUHf9.png)

I saw that there's so many questions & answers related to null pointer exception but no one worked for me. the ImageIcon is not being able to fetch the image. I even tried by creating a folder & gave the path but the error remains same.
Netbeans: 12.5
jdk:8
Please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
package com.mycompany.supershop;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.print.DocFlavor.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
public class add_image extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public add_image() {
        initComponents();
        
        ImageIcon img= new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("shop_removebg.png"))); 
        Image img1=img.getImage();
        Image img2 = img1.getScaledInstance(jLabel1.getWidth(),jLabel1.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon(img2);
        jLabel1.setIcon(i);


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 112, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(303, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(158, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }                      

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(add_image.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(add_image.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(add_image.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(add_image.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
      
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new add_image().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }            
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;                
}
```

The error shows,

```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.imageCached(SunToolkit.java:899)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.getImage(LWCToolkit.java:549)
    at com.mycompany.supershop.add_image.<init>(add_image.java:24)
    at com.mycompany.supershop.add_image$1.run(add_image.java:107)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is in this line,

```
ImageIcon img= new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("shop_removebg.png")));
```

images on request to show the errors:

> [picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGj1g.png) [picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Zrl.png) [picture3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ1XY.png) [picture4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqorU.png)

Comment: Add a slash before shop_removebg.png

Comment: @Jens i added but it shows the same error.

Comment: Where is the image located?

Comment: at the same folder of java file.

Comment: @Abra Thanks a lot.I'm trying the solutions.

Comment: *"I saw that there's so many questions & answers related to null pointer exception but no one worked for me."* Link the top 3 & explain why they did not work for you. We see questions like this every other day. with very little evidence the questioner has done even basic research.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i've added four pictures on my post. I tried in many ways.Still found no solution.

Comment: Please, do not post images of what should be 4 lines of code, or even more importantly, Four strings used as the arguments to `getResource`. The image did, however, reveal something important in the package / project structure. First a warning, the IDE might not even be including the image in the built jar. Resources usually go in a `resources` directory. But if the image ***is*** copied into the built resources, the valid path string will be `"/com/mycompany/supershop/shop_removebg.png"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndrewThompson . Now it's working & not showing nullPointerException but the image isn't showing in jlabel. You helped me to get rid of the main problem.Could you please tell me why the image is absent in jlabel?Please.. ..I tried these lines.
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/com/mycompany/supershop/shop_removebg.png");
        Image img1=icon.getImage();
        Image img2 = img1.getScaledInstance(jLabel1.getWidth(),jLabel1.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon(img2);
        jLabel1.setIcon(i);

Comment: "the IDE might not even be including the image in the built jar" how to check this &  get rid of this?

Comment: *"Could you please tell me why the image is absent.."* Possibly. Start a new question thread about that. It seems this one is solved (please accept answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the project structure, the valid path string to the image will be:

```
"/com/mycompany/supershop/shop_removebg.png"
```

Always use the `/` prefix to indicate a search from the root of the classpath.